# Capturing all the columns in a select statement except one from a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to select  all the columns except one in Snowflake like we have in [bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_except):

```
select * except(columnname) from table
```

Comment: There's no **except** like in BigQuery, you will have to select all columns you need like **SELECT COL1, COL2, ..., COLN FROM TABLE**

Comment: It can be done with Snowflake Scripting  the information schema's but not at a simple first order thing.

Comment: I wrote a script @SimeonPilgrim, what do you think?

Comment: Updated answer: Now this is supported natively!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 2022 update: Snowflake now supports EXCLUDE():

Test with:

```sql
with data as (
    select 1 col_a, 2 col_b, 3 col_c, 4 col_d
)

select *, col_a as id
    exclude (col_c, col_b, col_a)
from data
```

- https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/1593311749100294144

[image]

---

### Previous answer:

In lieu of the `EXCEPT` syntax, I wrote a stored procedure that can give you the list of columns to `SELECT` for:

```sql
create or replace procedure cols_except(table_name varchar, except varchar)
returns varchar
language sql as 
begin
    describe table identifier(:table_name);
    return (
        select listagg("name", ', ') cols_except
        from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) 
        where not array_contains("name"::variant, (split(:except, ','))) 
    );
end;
```

You can use it to get the columns to select for, after eliminating the values that match the except clause:

```sql
call cols_except('snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.nation', 'N_NAME,N_REGIONKEY');
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, I get errors creating the procedure..

Comment: but the parts work correctly..
`6.10.2` wow, I wrote a valid SQL command in front of the CREATE and now the procedure creates.

Comment: `01a37bbb-0601-583d-0058-de03000b43ee` `Statement NULL not found` OR
`Query 01a37bbb-0601-583d-0058-de03000b43ee has no result because it failed` on second run in worksheet. but after a `SELECT 1` the function creates.

Comment: But ignoring the Scripting creation bug, it works a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake supports natively `SELECT * EXCLUDE(<col_list>)` syntax:

```
SELECT * EXCLUDE id FROM tab1;

SELECT * EXCLUDE (id, col1) FROM tab1;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab1(id INT, col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT)
AS
SELECT 1, 'a', 'b';
```

Output:

[image]