# Snowflake/DBT - Checksum on the fly

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have to create a checksum column in the midst of running an insert statement (its a short term fix), and I would rather not have to hash a very wide table (400 columns). Is there any way to select or get all the columns from a table (and filter out a few) as a subquery and hash that rather than list each column in my query?

As a query using "show" does not work inline

```
select column_name from (
show columns in  table my.example.table)
where column_name not like 'example%'
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to compute hash value without specifying column list using [HASH(*)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash.html) and exclude specific columns using [SELECT * EXCLUDE(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74411170/5070879) syntax:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.hash_value,
       HASH(t1.col2, t1.col3) AS hash_value_explicit -- for debug only
FROM tab AS t1
,LATERAL (SELECT HASH(*) AS hash_value
          FROM (SELECT * EXCLUDE (id, col1) 
                FROM tab AS t2
                WHERE t1.id = t2.id)  -- correlation! unique key required
          ) AS t2;
```

For sample input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT 1 AS id, 'a' AS col1, 'b' AS col2, 'c' AS col3
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'b', 'c', 'd';
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: nice, how would I add that inline to a longer select statement ie , select many columns from a table and then add that checksum on the end of the select statement or will I need to create a CTE in order to do that?

Comment: @0004 The easiest way is to use CTE to wrap any other transformations and add the ,LATERAL ... part to the last query

Comment: hmm, is there anyway to just have it be a subqery, because the table could have multiple unique keys and so I'd rather not rely on a lateral join

Comment: @0004 Unfortunately `SELECT t1.*
,(SELECT HASH(*) 
  FROM (SELECT * EXCLUDE (id, col1) 
        FROM t1)
 ) AS hash_value
FROM tab AS t1 ` will not work

Comment: so I am trying to offset the fact that the table I am selecting from does not have a checksum column, but I want to insert a checksum value into the new table for traceability -- is this possible with the method you advised (ie instead of an ods table having a checksum, I am creating one on the fly so i can insert a checksum value into a new table) Does that make sense, I am just worried that if I join using lateral --- it will mix up records or is that not a concern?

Comment: From dbt perspective the column could be real column, constant or expression(here t2.hash_value). With model defined and materialized `{{ config(materialized='table') }}` the new column will be "persisted"

Comment: I created a new post  - so we can continue there (and you get more credit) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74605311/snowflake-dbt-incremental-table-inserting-checksum-value-on-the-fly